# How to sort a huge array of items by a specific order defined by an array?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

i need to implement some specfic sorting algorithm. I have two arrays:

```
$items = array(
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "alpha"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "beta"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "company"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "marketing"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "beta"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "company"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "alpha"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "alpha"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "company"),
  array("id" => "…", "type" => "marketing"),
  […]
);

$order = array("company", "marketing", "alpha", "beta" );
```

As you propably can imagine i need to sort `$items` according to the order specified in `$order`.

Comment: Where comes `$items` from? If they came from a database, can't you sort them directly during the query (using `ORDER BY`)?

Comment: i does not really come from the database at the point i am currently working at. I'd rather have a function `orderByArray($items, $order)`. Yet I could easily edit the query… would there be a way to eg. `ORDER type BY ("company", "marketing", "alpha", "beta")`?

Comment: `ORDER BY 'company' ORDER BY 'marketing'` and so on.

Comment: Well but that doesn't make much sense to me yet, since 'company' and 'marketing' are values of the `type` column. (Pseudo: `ORDER 'type' BY ("marketing",[…])`.

Comment: `ORDER BY type = "company" DESC, type = "marketing" DESC, ...`

Comment: Or use the [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function: `... ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'company', 'marketing', 'alpha', 'beta')`.

Comment: Whew! Didn't know about the field function. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort with a custom comparison function using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($items, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b)
{
  $order = array("company" => 0, "marketing" => 1, "alpha" => 2, "beta" => 3);

  $order_a = $order[$a["type"]];
  $order_b = $order[$b["type"]];

  if ($order_a == $order_b) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($order_a < $order_b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: All answers here would work, but since this made me understand how to use usort, I marked this one as the answer (and because my code now resembles mostly this one).

Answer (score 4):

Run through `$items` and index everything into a dictionary using "type" as the key. Then run through `$order` and lookup the list of items corresponding to that "type" and append them onto the sorted list. Runs in `O(n+k)`, k being `|order|`.

Comment: love the plain trivial feeling of this solution.  :D

Answer (score 2):

You can make a naïve implementation of a user sort function:

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
    global $order;

    return array_search($a['type'], $order) - array_search($b['type'], $order);
}
```

And then do a `usort()`:

```
usort($items, 'mySort');
```

Probably not very efficient, but it [works](http://www.ideone.com/uRy4u).

---

**UPDATE**
To avoid the many calls to `array_search()` you can flip the `$order` array once beforehand. This will replace `array_search()` with a simple look-up:

```
$reversed_order = array_flip($order);

function mySort($a, $b) {
    global $reversed_order;

    return $reversed_order[$a['type']] - $reversed_order[$b['type']];
}
```

Ought to be more efficient. ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/7YQAQ))

Comment: @duedl0r Not as efficient as sorting in the DB, I guess. Other than that it's pretty hard to tell given no indication of data size etc. Array look-ups [appear to be `O(1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641052/time-space-complexity-of-php-array) so the updated solution is probably better than the first. (That was the intention, after all.)

Comment: @duedl0r Also, the `usort()` is probably a [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), just like [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to Ozgur!! However, I'd build in functionality to also handle unexpected values that are not considered in the order. They placed at the end of the sorted array.

```
usort($items,"compare");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($items);
echo "</pre>";

function compare($a, $b) {
  $order = array("company" => 1, "marketing" => 2, "alpha" => 3, "beta" => 4);
  $ax = $order[$a['type']]; $bx = $order[$b['type']];    
  if ($ax < 1) return 1;
  if ($ax == $bx) return 0;
  return ($ax > $bx) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use usort , which is efficient PHP algorithm, and can run based on conditions you provide.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Here is a running code, you can benchmark it for your data :
http://codepad.org/MRpZQkKk

This would give you more control if you want to alter sorting criterias,
also complexity wise its pretty fast, should be O(n log n) ( quicksort internally ),
and space complexity is also low.

Here is more on it :
[Which sort algorithms does PHP's usort apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907680/which-sort-algorithms-does-phps-usort-apply)

```
  <?php

    $items = array(
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "alpha"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "beta"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "company"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "marketing"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "beta"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "company"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "alpha"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "alpha"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "company"),
      array("id" => "…", "type" => "marketing"),

    );

    $order = array("company", "marketing", "alpha", "beta" );

    $orderIndexes = array(); /* cache indexes of the order keys */
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($order) ; $i++ )
    {
       $orderIndexes[$order[$i]] = $i ;
    }


    /* we have something like :
    $orderIndexes = array('company' => 0 , 'marketing' => 1 , ....);
    */



    function myCriteria($item1,$item2)   /* this is the function used to decide order */
    {  global $orderIndexes;
       $index1 = $orderIndexes[$item1['type']];
       $index2 = $orderIndexes[$item2['type']];

       return $index1 - $index2 ;    // negative means $item1 precedes $item2

    }

usort($items,"myCriteria");
print_r($items);

?>
```