# How to view the steps of the usort() in PHP?

Tags: php, usort

This is the Example #1 from the php.net usort() page:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

The usort function takes the values within the array as pairs ($a-$b; so this is - 3-2, 2-5, 5-6, 6-1) and moves the $b value depending on whether the cmp() function returns -1, 0 or 1. If it is -1 the $b gets moved down (within a current pair), if it is 0 it stays in the same place and if it is 1 it gets moved up. This is how this is suppose to be working based on the top comment from the php.net manual usort() page.

Is there any way to see how this works step by step (the sorting process)? Am I able to see it or is it only possible to see the final result after the sorting is done? I want to understand fully how this process works.

Comment: Can I write a piece of PHP code that would enable me to see the steps of this particular usort() sorting?

Comment: PHP implements a sorting algorithm and, when it needs to compare two items, it uses the callback you provide as the second argument to `usort()`. There are dozens of sorting algorithms. PHP probably uses quicksort (it's one of the fastest sorting algorithms); you can find out by checking the PHP sources. You can, as well, let the comparison function display information about its arguments. If you are good on sorting algorithms then you can identify it based on this information. If you are not, well, I guess it doesn't help you too much (and you need to learn some sorting algorithms).

Comment: Yes, I think that this is the usort based on the top comment on this manual page. I am wondering if I can see the steps of this. Or probably not? It just gives the result when it is finished / at the end? I guess if this is quicksort I would need to look into how this works. EDIT: So probably no way to see it from the php level and just look into the Quicksort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some debug output in your comparison function you can only see the comparisons that PHP does, but can't see intermediate states of the array.

But the algorithm used in usort is well known - it's QuickSort ( [Which sort algorithms does PHP's usort apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907680/which-sort-algorithms-does-phps-usort-apply) ).

You can see its vizualisation at http://www.algomation.com/algorithm/quick-sort-visualization (or just google "quicksort algorithm visualization")

Comment: I figured out that I can mix in echo statements and also use var_dump - this would show me how the code behaves. It looks like the array does not change in the middle on the process and it only changes at the end.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5z0m1Yvp - With this piece of code it looks like the usort creates 12 separate $a and $b pairs and until this point i was thinking that it would be six - 2-1, 1-3, 3-4, 4-2, 2-1, 1-2. This is actually something like this 2-1, 2-3, 1-3, 2-4, 3-4, 2-2, 2-1, 2-1 (the same pair again?), 4-1, 3-1, 1-1, 2-2. This returns 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.